# Can't generate cscope.out file

Tags: linux, cscope

I am using cscope on a  project  which locates in author/trunk/ .
Under "author" directory  cscope -R worked well and generated cscope.out. However when using same commmand on a subdirectory like author/trunk/../dhcp, no cscope .out was generated ,and had "no cscope connection" when I wanted to search in  one file
So what should I do  now ,THanks

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend using `cscope -bkqR` instead of the simpler `cscope -R`.

Second, I think you need to start `cscope` in the same directory where `cscope.out` is located or you'll get the error you mentioned. At least, this is true for `vim`.

Comment: Hi,Thansk very much .I understand "need to start cscope in the same directory where cscope.out is located". I just failed to generate "cscope.out" in subdirectory. That's real problem . I think "cscope -bkqR" is supposed to do that .But it did not .